# Intersection of squares/cubes/hypercubes.

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry, solid-geometry

One can form a polygon of $4 n$ sides by intersecting $n$ congruent squares (treated as closed sets, i.e., filled squares):

        
[image: Three Squares]

> **Q1**. For which of the $k=3,4,\ldots,4n$ can the intersection of $n$ congruent squares
>   result in a $k$-gon?  Perhaps not all can be achieved?
>
> **Q2**. Can the intersection of $n$ congruent cubes result in a polyhedron of $6 n$ faces? I believe so, but an explicit construction would be useful.
>
> **Q3**.  For which $k$ can $k$-face polyhedra result from the intersection of $n$ congruent cubes?
>
> **Q4**. The questions extend to $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Question **Q2** in particular occurred to me as a possible exercise to build 3D intuition.

**Added**. Here are two cubes intersected to produce a polyhedron of 12 faces
(although one can hardly verify that from this single, not well-lighted image!):

        
[image: Two Cubes]

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but my count would be $8n$ sides. From that count, one obvious necessary condition would be that $k$ be divisible by 8 (if you rule out the possibility that two squares coincide).

Comment: @Manolito: For the $n{=}3$ squares illustrated, the intersection consists of $4n=12$ edges. Note one can intersect two squares and get a triangle, so $k{=}3$ is achievable.

Comment: OK, now I see. I misunderstood when you said 'filled' squares.

Comment: @Manolito: I tried to revise to block that misintepretation: sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Any configuration of regular polytopes, where no two polytopes have a pair of parallell planes, and every plane is symmetric wrt. to the configuration, and the intersection is nonempty, should give the max faces.

For Q2 and n odd, we can rotate each cube around an internal diagonal like this[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Question 2 :**

Even though OP asks about cubes I would like to comment some about
squares. There is $n$ squares of **side length** $2$ s.t. all
centers of squares $A_i,\ 1\leq i\leq n $ is located at the origin
in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If $v_i$ is a **unit vector** in any one side of $A_i$, then
assume that the angle between $x$-axis and $v_i$ is strictly larger
than $0$ and strictly smaller than $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Note that each $v_i$ determines the $i$-th square uniquely. Further
if $$\sharp\{v_1,\cdots , v_n\}=n,$$ then side corresponded to $v_i$
survives in the intersection of $n$ squares. Hence if we choose $n$ different vectors $v_i$ with that angle
condition, then we have $4n$-polygon.

Now we will consider about $n$ cubes :

We will use the similar idea.
If $C_i$ are cubes with side length $2$ and origin center, then we
have orthonormal frame $\{a_i,b_i,c_i\}$ s.t. each vectors are in
sides, and then $a_ib_ic_i$ is an equilateral spherical triangle of side
length $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

If $x$ is a point in $\mathbb{S}^2$, then
there is $r$ s.t. geodesic sphere $S(r,x)$ in $\mathbb{S}^2$
contains $a_i,\ b_i,\ c_i$ for all $i$. If $y\in S(r,x)$, then we
are sufficient to take $a_i$ sufficiently close to $y$, differently,
which completes the proof.